# The method FB.x.x is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed

Tags: javascript, facebook

I recently received a notice from Facebook that read as follow:

> As announced in the Facebook Developer blog, Facebook is in the process of removing methods >from the Javascript SDK that are not officially supported. Your app "*" (*) has been >identified as using such methods, and we are informing you about this now so that you can >make the necessary changes to avoid your application being affected when we first make these >methods into empty stubs, and subsequently when we remove them.
>
> To find out which changes you need to make, please check the developer console while running >your app, and validate against the official documentation.

There does not seem to be much information on the web about specifically what methods are being tagged for deprecation. I ran a script from the browser console that basically executed just about every method on the FB object and I came up with the follow list of methods that result in the warning: "The method FB.x.x is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed."

The list can be found here as it is rather long:
http://www.codesauce.com/facebook_js_sdk_deprecations.html

Hopefully it helps out others!

Answer (score 1):

I used chrome developer tools console with the following JS snippet to execute any method attached to the FB object:

```
for (var i in FB) {
    console.log(i);
    if (typeof FB[i] == 'function') { 
        try { FB[i](); } catch (e) { }
    }
    for (var j in FB[i]) {
        if (typeof FB[i][j] == 'function') {
            console.log("\t" + j);
            try { FB[i][j](); } catch (e) { }
        }
    }
    console.log(Array(10).join("-"));
}
```

Then copied this output to a file.. clean it up to only take anything that starts with "The method"

`sed -i '/The method/p' console_output`

And finally searched my codebase for the call:

`grep -iPo "FB\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+" console_output | xargs -I% ack-grep % path/to/mycodebase`